# Proof of tracelessness of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ generators

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

When discussing special unitary groups of matrices, in all books there is a claim that is never proven. It is, that all generators of this group are traceless. On what basis is this claim made?

Comment: That assertion makes no sense. If $SU(n)$ is generated by a set $S$, then adding $\operatorname{Id}$ to $S$ doesn't change that fact that it is a generator set. But the trace of $\operatorname{Id}$ is $n$. Where did you see this assertion?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#Fundamental_representation

Comment: Your link is about generators of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$, not about generators of $SU(n)$.

Comment: well... every country has a different notation I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\xi \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$ is an infinitesimal generator (i.e. $\exp(t \xi) \in SU(n)$), then $\det \exp(t \xi) = 1$ for each $t$  and thus $\frac d{dt}|_{t = 0}\det \exp(t \xi) = 0$. Applying [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)  we can write this derivative as $$0 = \mathrm{tr}\left( \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0}\exp(t \xi)\right)=\mathrm{tr} (\xi).$$

Comment: It is also common to prove this by using the fact that
$$
\det(\exp(t \xi)) = \exp(\operatorname{tr}(t \xi))
$$